# Understanding binary conversion implementation in C++ with bit operations

Tags: c++, malloc, bit-shift

I am interested in understanding the implementation of converting decimal to binary. Could somebody clarify the purpose of using left-shift and Right-shift in the following code?

```
void static inline unsignedToBinary(unsigned x, char*& bin)
{
  bin = (char*) malloc(33);

  int p = 0;
  for (unsigned i = (1 << 31); i > 0; i >>= 1)
    bin[p++] = ((x&i) == i) ? '1' : '0';
  bin[p] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: This is a great opportunity to learn to use your debugger. Step through line by line looking at the variables.

Comment: Why? Because binary.

Comment: Regarding `bin = (char*) malloc(33);`, can we talk you into `std::vector<char> static inline unsignedToBinary(unsigned x)` with `std::vector<char> bin(33);` or at least `bin = new char[33];` with a check to make sure whatever was at `bin` wasn't just leaked?

Comment: Ask the person who wrote it. (Then tell them to stop writing such bad code!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a straightforward implementation of binary conversion that uses bit operations.

- Variable `i` represents the *mask* - an `int` containing 2<sup>k</sup> value, where `k` is the position of the bit.
- The initial value is 2<sup>31</sup>, produced with left-shifting `1` by 31.
- `for` loop uses `>>= 1` to right-shift the mask until `1` gets shifted out of it, making `i == 0`.
- At each iteration `x&i` is compared to `i`. The comparison succeeds when `x` contains `1` in the position where `i` has its `1`; it fails otherwise.

**Note:** Although using `malloc` in C++ is certainly allowed, it is not ideal. If you want to stay with C strings, use `new char[33]` instead. A more C++-like approach would be using `std::string`.

Comment: Thanks!
How can I implement negative numbers to binary?



    void static inline swordToBinary(int x, char*& bin)
{
 
}

Comment: @Sepideha The same implementation is going to work. You will see the actual representation on your system, which will almost certainly include lots of ones at the beginning of the number.